# Get the next record using while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not allowed to use cursor, or temp tables.  I have to use a while loop only.

Table1 - Readonly Table (non editable)

```
id name

M01 Raja
M02 Ravi
M03 Vijay
M04 suresh
```

Query

```
Declare @TotRecord int, @CurrRecord Int, @id varchar(10)

Select @TotRec = COUNT(*) from Table1
Set @CurrRec = 1
WHILE (@CurrRec <=@TotRec)
BEGIN

--*Here i want to get the id from table, 
--next time i need to get second id. 
--next time i need to get third id.
--....

--1st time i can get the top 1 id by using this below query 
Select top 1 @id  = id from table 
--Next time i want to get second id.*


SET @CurrRec = @CurrRec + 1
END
```

Comment: what about a table variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pattern of

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE id > @iterator ORDER BY id ASC
```

in a loop

Answer (score 0):

If ID is sequence number (M01, M02, M03,...), then you can use the following with in while loop

```
SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM table WHERE CAST(REPLACE(id,'M','') AS INT)  = @CurrRecord
```

Full Query

```
DECLARE @TotRecord INT, @CurrRecord INT, @id VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @TotRecord = COUNT(*) FROM Table1
SET @CurrRecord = 1
WHILE @CurrRecord <= @TotRecord
BEGIN
    -- Get ID
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM Table1 WHERE CAST(REPLACE(id,'M','') AS INT) = @CurrRecord

    -- Do something

    SET @CurrRecord = @CurrRecord + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor for get records of your query one to one.

For example :

```
Declare @Col1 INT,
        @Col2 INT,
        ...


DECLARE X CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Col1, col2 , ...
FROM YourTableName


OPEN X
FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @Col1, @Col2, ...
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
    --your code to do with columns data of your record
    FETCH NEXT FROM X INTO @Col1, @Col2, ...
END
CLOSE X
DEALLOCATE X
```

You can also use where for your idea:

```
DECLARE @Id INT,
        @OldId INT,
        @Col1 INT,
        @Col2 INT
        ...

WHILE 1=1 BEGIN

    SET @OldId = @Id
    SET @Id = NULL

    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id, 
                 @Col1 = Column1,
                 @Col2 = Column2
    FROM YourTable 
    WHERE (@OldId IS NULL OR Id > @OldId) ORDER BY Id

    IF @Id IS NULL BREAK

    -- your Code Here
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TotRecord INT;
DECLARE @CurrRecord INT;
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10);

SELECT @TotRecord = COUNT(*) from Table1;
SELECT @CurrRecord = 1;
SELECT TOP 1 @id  = id FROM Table1 ORDER BY id; 
WHILE (@CurrRecord <= @TotRecord)
BEGIN
    --Do something...
    --Get the next id
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM Table1 WHERE id > @id ORDER BY id;
    SELECT @CurrRecord = @CurrRecord + 1;
END;
```

But note that this will only work if the id is unique in Table1.

Comment: `id` is a VARCHAR field

Comment: @Jesuraja surely some creative parsing and casting would do the job

Comment: Even if id is a VARCHAR field it doesn't matter as long as it is unique.  Yes, you won't get data back in the order you might expect but you will get each row processed once and once only...  If the order is important then you could parse it by removing the "M" first?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Declare @TotRecord int, @CurrRecord Int, @id varchar(10)

    Select @TotRec = COUNT(*) from Table1
    Set @CurrRec = 1
    WHILE (@CurrRec <=@TotRec)
    BEGIN

    select LAST(id) from (SELECT TOP  @CurrRec id
    FROM Table1);

    //Here you will get the last record, i havent tried this, but iam sure about the logic , hope this one helps

    SET @CurrRec = @CurrRec + 1
    END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select id,name,row_number() over (order by id) 'Row' into #temp
from table 

Select @id =  id from #temp where row = @current
```

Use temp table to get the next id

Comment: he said he didn't want to use temp tables or cursors :D